# Twitter Bootstrap avoid offset in tablet

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tablet, offset

I have a:

```
<div class="row span6 offset3">
```

in Twitter Bootstrap. I'm using responsive layout (not fluid), and I'm pretty happy with the way it looks in desktop and phone. But it looks very narrow in tablet. I would like to get rid of the offset3 for the row when I'm on a tablet.

What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what finally works for me:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) 
{
    [class*="span"],input[class*="span"]{
        width: 95%;
        margin-left: 0;
    }
}
```

Absolutely not sure if this is the proper way to do it, this is my first project with Bootstrap. I have to say I like it a lot, works really great. With a better documentation would be even better.